# How to stop "Monkey Test" and "Time Service" apps

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

When I long-press the "home" button to close all apps, there is an app named "time service" with android symbol and another named "monkey test" that are always open.

How to stop this?

Comment: Take screenshot when you see those symbols or apps, edit the screenshot to point them, and then share the screenshot with us.

Comment: seems like this is related to: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120541/how-to-delete-a-file-e-g-malware-app-that-cannot-be-even-removed-with-root-ac

Answer (score 2):

"Monkey Test" and "Time Service" are being reported recently by some anti-virus programs for Android as malware, as reported [here](https://community.norton.com/en/forums/monkey-test-time-service-malware-s) in the Norton Community forum, and [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-apps/541154-monkey-test-time-service.html) at Android Central. In general form, they suggest the normal actions:

- Disabling installations from "Unknown Sources",
   Settings -> Security -> Device administration -> Unknown sources
- Disabling the app,
   Settings -> Application manager -> *AppName* -> Disable/Uninstall
- Checking to see if "Device Administrators" has it blocked from uninstalling, and then trying the uninstall again.
   Settings -> Security -> Device administration - > Device administrators
- Factory Reset

Both communities also suggest the use of some uninstallers for malware, which I won't cover here, in addition to rooting as a final option to totally remove it/them.