# How to stop coreservice walton primo GF3

Tags: malware, antivirus

Monkeytest and Timeservice were annoying me so I reset my phone which caused great problems in my phone. Now I think my phone is affected by a virus named core service, and my phone works very slowly and after some time it switches off automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a file (e.g. malware app) that cannot be even removed with root access?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120541/how-to-delete-a-file-e-g-malware-app-that-cannot-be-even-removed-with-root-ac)

Comment: Related: [Attempted multiple solutions for malwares like androidSystem, timeService and monkeyTest, but to no avail](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125408)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempted multiple solutions for malwares like androidSystem, timeService and monkeyTest, but to no avail](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125408/attempted-multiple-solutions-for-malwares-like-androidsystem-timeservice-and-mo)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways out of this problem:

a. Completely flash your phone's firmware (ROM) if you can find and download the firmware for your phone..

b. Root your phone and uninstall all the apps related to that malware app using apps like Link2SD or whatever (because those malware apps would have been installed as system apps)..

Just search in google or http://forum.xda-developers.com to find out how to root your phone..
You can also try the apps like Kingroot or Framaroot which may root your device..