# How to remove monkey test and time service?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, malware

I am using a *Micromax Canvas A116.* ***It's not a rooted phone.*** I've done a factory-reset, but still malware app existing. How to remove monkey test, time service in mobile phone? And everytime phone gets reboot and unwanted apps like get touch, paytm etc., get installed. How to resolve this?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

I tried all the possible ways [suggested in this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120368/43602)

Comment: I done everything as suggested on that but still it's not removed. additional app like easy touch and other apps too gets installed.

Comment: @HakunaMatata - This is why I would not comment on the uninstallers in my original answer. I believe they are merely other avenues to OTHER malware. Getting rid of malware is hard, once you are infected. Let everyone know at the other question, with the correct procedure, when you have resolved it.