# How can I install e2fsprogs on my device?

Tags: adb, command-line

My phone has the "Monkey Test" virus and there is solution in [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/fix-monkey-test-time-service-virus-t3194907), but when I try to execute this command:

```
chattr -iaA providerCertificate.apk
```

I receive the error "chattr : not found".

I found a solution [here](http://blog.droidzone.in/2014/01/19/chattr-command-not-found/), which is to install `e2fsprogs`, but I don't know how to install it using ADB. How can i install it?

Comment: Related: [How to stop "Monkey Test" and "Time Service" apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120362)

Comment: Read carefully: That e2fsprogs link and anything related to it is irrelevant to your problem. If you're having issue such as "chattr : not found" then most likely either you didn't install [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) or you did install but didn't open it and followed the binaries installation. I've it installed and `chattr` binary works fine. Follow that XDA thread carefully.

Comment: Also, please keep this in mind: "*[If people are seriously copying any command they don't understand on the internet and pasting it into a shell to see what happens, they probably aren't going to last very long.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3631/105083)*", because you need to know what you're doing.